# How do I obtain an email address with Unicode in it?

Tags: email, unicode, unicode-string

I am trying to obtain an email address with unicode in it. Like екзампл@example.com. I've tried Chinese websites (http://www.sina.com.cn/), gmail.com, and even my own hosting site on namecheap. They all have requirements for only ASCII characters. I am trying to test and update a library, but want to test on a real email address with unicode in it.

Comment: Google has plans to enable this for gmail.com addresses. They've just announced the ability to send and receive e-mail messages to accounts on other sites that have non-ASCII characters. Details here: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/08/a-first-step-toward-more-global-email.html

Answer (score 3):

You will not find any major mail service that supports unicode mailboxes now days. Probably you will not find at least a single mail service of such kind.

Instead you may try to register IDN encoded mailbox (I am not sure you will succeed, but I read couple of blog articles telling that trick worked in the past at mail.ru). IDN encoded mailbox will be like that:

`чат@mail.ru xn--80a0bn@mail.ru`

If you wish to get pure unicode mailbox, you will need to wait some more time (years, I guess). Though there is RFC 6530 since 2012, unicode mailboxes still aren't available at major mail services (like Google, Yandex, Yahoo, etc.) and mail server software (e.g.: Postfix).

According to RFC 6530 an SMPTUTF8-capable MTA can't forward email with an SMPTUTF8 sender address to a non-SMPTUTF8 MTA. Email must be returned as undelivered (sections 8 and 9 of RFC 6530).

Therefore, even if you will get an RFC 6530 compliant mail server, it will be useless, until RFC 6530 will be supported by vast majority of mail servers of Internet.